# Why don't numeric cells have a .Characters() property?

Tags: vba, excel, character, number-formatting

With any text value, I can individually format each character and then copy that formatting to another cell by iterating over the `Range.Characters()` Collection.

However, if the cell is a number (even if the numberFormatting displays it as a string e.g. dates) then it does not expose a `.Characters()` property and, indeed, cannot be selectively formatted digit-by-digit.

Why does Excel display strings using Character objects but not numbers, even when the number is being displayed as a string?

Comment: If the number is formatted as text (i.e. *'displayed as a string'*) then you can format individual characters/digits. If it is formatted as a number then 10 is not 10, it is 0A.

Comment: @Jeeped I get that text can be formatted as a series of characters. What I **thought** was the case was the Characters() objects were used as a presentation-layer (especially for things like dateValues displayed as written dates). for any values, but apparently not for numbers. I'm just trying to find out what's **actually** going on.

Comment: The truth might scare you. You can take the blue pill and see a `Range` object with magical properties, or you can take the red pill, faceoff with COM and the "real" Excel object model, and see how deep the rabbit hole goes. I liked the blue pill.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go around this, you may do the following:

In cell A1 put '123456 with the " ' " sign in front.
Then write

```
range("A1").Characters(1,3).Font.Bold = true
```

It would take only the first three numbers, not taking into account the " ' " sign. Thus, the number is kind of displayed as a string, but you can still use it calculations e.g. A1 + 4 would give 123460.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, but I'm not interested in workarounds so much as understanding **why** they are different and what's actually happening "under the hood" to cause the difference.

Comment: The idea is that a number is always a number in the cell, even when it is formatted to look like text. VBA does not care how it looks like in Excel in this case - it knows that it is a number and thus it cannot be have Range.Characters. For a similar reason you cannot name a variable, starting with number in VBA, e.g. 123_my_variable.